# Postgresql COALESCE does not set default value

Tags: sql, postgresql, outer-join

I have two tables:

**tcars**

```
 id  |         name        |  car_price 
 ----|---------------------|------------
  1  |First_car_name       |       1000 
  2  |Second_car_name      |       1200
```

**tcar_optionals**

```
 id | id_car   | spec |  opt_included   |price
----|----------|------|-------------------------
 1  |       2  |Spec1 |  true           |   500 
 2  |       2  |Spec2 |  true           |   100 
 3  |       2  |Spec3 |  false          |   500 
 4  |       2  |Spec4 |  true           |     0 
 5  |       1  |Spec5 |  false          |   500 
 6  |       1  |Spec6 |  true           |     0
```

And the following query:

```
select t1.id, coalesce(t1.car_price, 0)+ coalesce(sum(t2.price), 0) as total_price
from tcars t1
    left join tcar_optionals t2 on t2.id_car = t1.id
where t2.opt_included and t2.price>0 and t1.id=?
group by t1.id, t1.car_price
```

It returns the id from tcars and the total_price(car_price+price of included optionals that have price>0).

Example:

for `t1.id=2` returns:

```
 id | total_price
----|------------
 2  | 1800
```

The problem appears when I have no included optionals with price>0, for example t1.id = 1.

What it returns:

```
 id | total_price
----|------------
```

What I need is return only t1.car_price as total_price if there are no included optionals with price>0:

```
 id | total_price
----|------------
 1  |      1000
```

Can someone help me with this problem, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```html
select (t1.car_price + coalesce(extra_price, 0)) as start_price
from tcars t1
left join (select id_car,sum(price) as extra_price from tcar_optionals 
where opt_included and price > 0 group by 1) q1 on q1.id_car = t1.id
where t1.id=$1
```

Answer (score 2):

The condition `q1.id_car=1` in the **where** clause effectively turns your outer join into an inner join because for rows not matching the join condition `q1.id_car` will be null and the comparison `=1` will remove those rows again.

You would need to put that into the **JOIN condition** - but as you already have a condition on the `id_car` in the derived table ("q1"), you don't need it anyway.

The other possibility would be to filter on the corresponding value from the `tcars` table: `where t1.id = 1`

---

**Edit**

By moving the conditions on the t2 table to the join condition you do get what you want:

```
select t1.id, coalesce(t1.car_price, 0) + coalesce(sum(t2.price), 0) as total_price
from tcars t1
    left join tcar_optionals t2 
           on t2.id_car = t1.id 
          and t2.opt_included and t2.price > 0 --<< conditions for tcar_optionals go here
where t1.id = 1   --<< limit the car you want to see
group by t1.id;
```

If `id` is defined as the primary key in `tcars`, then `group by t1.id` is enough.

See the example here: http://rextester.com/YOYF30261

Comment: I need the q1.id_car=1; for returning the price of a specific car, if I remove this line, the query will return the price for all cars in my db

Comment: @Kuzuri: You can limit the overall result to just one car by using `where t1.id = 1`

Comment: I know that, what I need from this query is to return only car's price if I have no included optionals.
Let's say that I have two cars: id=1,id=2 in tcars and id_car=1, id_car=2 in tcar_specs. First car's price is 1000 and I have two included optionals (first's price is 100 and second 150), the query will return 1250, the second car's (id_car=2) price is 900 and I have no included optionals, for this car the query should return 900 but it doesn't, it returns nothing.

Comment: @Kuzuri: Sorry, I don't understand your problem. If you only want one car, the limit the query to that. If you want both cars, the don't. You should **edit** your question and add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. ([Formatted](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) text please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557))

Answer (score 2):

You should firstly join the tables with all conditions on the second table and aggregate values from this (joined) result, e.g:

```
select id, coalesce(car_price, 0)+ coalesce(sum(price), 0) total_price
from tcars
left join tcar_optionals on id = id_car and spec_included
-- where id = 1
group by id, car_price
```

Comment: Same result, no row if I don't have included optionals

Comment: It's just impossible. Did you change something in my query? See [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!15/07296/1)